# iOS 5 - Webview - Scale to fit

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview

I am showing HTML in a webview. 
The HTML looks great but I can not Zoom.

To enable zoom I have to enable "Scales Page to fit". If I enable that the pages look horrible  and small. I want to keep the same layout that I can see when scales page to fit is disabled but I need zoom to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a trick to make it look good.

I changed scale page to fit to true (to enable zoom) and my page looked horrible. So I added the following line to the HTML head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
```

And everything looks good again!

If you want to change Scale page to fit to true (to enable zoom) and don't want to change all the stylesheets, this trick worked for me.

Comment: I personally prefer "width=device-width" but this was the solution! kudos

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes web pages look really bad when loaded into UIWebView control. You could try a trick like setting your own value of scale for the web page displayed. For example, you could define a method of UIWebViewDelegate like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom=1.7;"];
}
```

The value of zoom you should figure out by yourself, it actually depends on the look of the web page.

Comment: My webpage looks great, It is broken when I am using Scale to Fit option

Comment: Scale to Fit option depends on the mechanism of UIWebView determining the width of an HTML page based on it DOM representation. It may be inaccurate under some circumstances, depending on HTML layout.

Comment: Ok, but returning to my questions. Is there any way to zoom the webview setting Scale to fit to false?

Comment: Only as described in my answer. That is the simple line of Javascript code that is applied to HTML document body zooming it to the magnitude of your choice.

Comment: Tony, if you are still experiencing this issue, could you show your HTML page? You could remove all sensitive information from it, just leave the layout that causes the page look bad as you display it with "Scale to Fit" turned on.

Comment: I will post the HTML in the following hours. Thanks.

Comment: It worked but broke some styles, I will have to adjust them. It is the best answer possible, I hope I could have another option =(

Comment: I found another trick to make it look better, check out my answer.
Thanks!